# terraform apply command recreating the databricks workspace again

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, terraform, databricks, azure-databricks

This is regarding one of the issue which we are facing while creating the Databricks workspace instance using terraform. We are using Azure DevOps to execute the terraform commands in release pipeline using Terraform Tasks.

So the problem is that every time **terraform apply** command is running, it is destroying the existing Databricks workspace instance and recreating again.

Earlier we were using the Terraform Tasks and we were facing this issue, then we decided to go for Azure Power Shell tasks to execute the Terraform Commands as a part of Azure Release Pipeline to check if the Terraform Tasks are creating issue.

But even after using the Azure Power Shell tasks in release pipeline, problem is same.

**Terraform Version : 0.13.0**

**Provider file details**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id = "XXXXXXXX"
  tenant_id       = "XXXXXXXX"
  client_id       = "XXXXXXXX"
  client_secret = "XXXXXXX"
  use_msi = true
  features {}
  version = "2.71.0"
}

terraform {
backend "azurerm" {
  storage_account_name     = "name of storage account"
  container_name           = "name of the container"
  key = "name of the state file"
  access_key = "Access key for storage account"
 }
}
```

**Terraform plan**

```
{
    "format_version": "0.1",
    "terraform_version": "0.13.5",
    "variables": {
    }, 
          
    "planned_values": {
       "root_module": {
          "resources": [
             {
                "address": "azurerm_databricks_workspace.example-databricks",
                "mode": "managed",
                "type": "azurerm_databricks_workspace",
                "name": "example-databricks",
                "provider_name": "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm",
                "schema_version": 0,
                "values": {
                   "customer_managed_key_enabled": false,
                   "infrastructure_encryption_enabled": false,
                   "load_balancer_backend_address_pool_id": null,
                   "location": "westeurope",
                   "managed_services_cmk_key_vault_key_id": null,
                   "name": "databricks-test",
                   "public_network_access_enabled": true,
                   "resource_group_name": "example-databricks-resources",
                   "sku": "standard",
                   "tags": {
                      "Environment": "Production"
                   },
                   "timeouts": null
                }
             },
             {
                "address": "azurerm_resource_group.example-databricks",
                "mode": "managed",
                "type": "azurerm_resource_group",
                "name": "example-databricks",
                "provider_name": "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm",
                "schema_version": 0,
                "values": {
                   "id": "/subscriptions/XXXXXX/resourceGroups/example-databricks-resources",
                   "location": "westeurope",
                   "name": "example-databricks-resources",
                   "tags": {},
                   "timeouts": null
                }
             }
          ]
       }
    },
    "resource_changes": [
       {
          "address": "azurerm_databricks_workspace.example-databricks",
          "mode": "managed",
          "type": "azurerm_databricks_workspace",
          "name": "example-databricks",
          "provider_name": "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm",
          "change": {
             "actions": [
                "delete",
                "create"
             ],
             "before": {
                "custom_parameters": [
                   {
                      "machine_learning_workspace_id": "",
                      "nat_gateway_name": "nat-gateway",
                      "no_public_ip": false,
                      "private_subnet_name": "",
                      "private_subnet_network_security_group_association_id": "",
                      "public_ip_name": "nat-gw-public-ip",
                      "public_subnet_name": "",
                      "public_subnet_network_security_group_association_id": "",
                      "storage_account_name": "dbstorageaifs5gs73fjtu",
                      "storage_account_sku_name": "Standard_GRS",
                      "virtual_network_id": "",
                      "vnet_address_prefix": "10.139"
                   }
                ],
                "customer_managed_key_enabled": false,
                "id": "/subscriptions/XXXXXX/resourceGroups/example-databricks-resources/providers/Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces/databricks-test",
                "infrastructure_encryption_enabled": false,
                "load_balancer_backend_address_pool_id": null,
                "location": "westeurope",
                "managed_resource_group_id": "/subscriptions/XXXXXX/resourceGroups/databricks-rg-example-databricks-resources",
                "managed_resource_group_name": "databricks-rg-example-databricks-resources",
                "managed_services_cmk_key_vault_key_id": null,
                "name": "databricks-test",
                "network_security_group_rules_required": null,
                "public_network_access_enabled": false,
                "resource_group_name": "example-databricks-resources",
                "sku": "standard",
                "storage_account_identity": [],
                "tags": {
                   "Environment": "Production"
                },
                "timeouts": null,
                "workspace_id": "XXXXXX",
                "workspace_url": "adb-XXXXXX.12.azuredatabricks.net"
             },
             "after": {
                "customer_managed_key_enabled": false,
                "infrastructure_encryption_enabled": false,
                "load_balancer_backend_address_pool_id": null,
                "location": "westeurope",
                "managed_services_cmk_key_vault_key_id": null,
                "name": "databricks-test",
                "public_network_access_enabled": true,
                "resource_group_name": "example-databricks-resources",
                "sku": "standard",
                "tags": {
                   "Environment": "Production"
                },
                "timeouts": null
             },
             "after_unknown": {
                "custom_parameters": true,
                "id": true,
                "managed_resource_group_id": true,
                "managed_resource_group_name": true,
                "network_security_group_rules_required": true,
                "storage_account_identity": true,
                "tags": {},
                "workspace_id": true,
                "workspace_url": true
             }
          }
       },
       {
          "address": "azurerm_resource_group.example-databricks",
          "mode": "managed",
          "type": "azurerm_resource_group",
          "name": "example-databricks",
          "provider_name": "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm",
          "change": {
             "actions": [
                "no-op"
             ],
             "before": {
                "id": "/subscriptions/XXXXXX/resourceGroups/example-databricks-resources",
                "location": "westeurope",
                "name": "example-databricks-resources",
                "tags": {},
                "timeouts": null
             },
             "after": {
                "id": "/subscriptions/XXXXXX/resourceGroups/example-databricks-resources",
                "location": "westeurope",
                "name": "example-databricks-resources",
                "tags": {},
                "timeouts": null
             },
             "after_unknown": {}
          }
       }
    ],
    "prior_state": {
       "format_version": "0.1",
       "terraform_version": "0.13.5",
       "values": {
          "root_module": {
             "resources": [
                {
                   "address": "azurerm_databricks_workspace.example-databricks",
                   "mode": "managed",
                   "type": "azurerm_databricks_workspace",
                   "name": "example-databricks",
                   "provider_name": "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm",
                   "schema_version": 0,
                   "values": {
                      "custom_parameters": [
                         {
                            "machine_learning_workspace_id": "",
                            "nat_gateway_name": "nat-gateway",
                            "no_public_ip": false,
                            "private_subnet_name": "",
                            "private_subnet_network_security_group_association_id": "",
                            "public_ip_name": "nat-gw-public-ip",
                            "public_subnet_name": "",
                            "public_subnet_network_security_group_association_id": "",
                            "storage_account_name": "dbstorageaifs5gs73fjtu",
                            "storage_account_sku_name": "Standard_GRS",
                            "virtual_network_id": "",
                            "vnet_address_prefix": "10.139"
                         }
                      ],
                      "customer_managed_key_enabled": false,
                      "id": "/subscriptions/XXXXXX/resourceGroups/example-databricks-resources/providers/Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces/databricks-test",
                      "infrastructure_encryption_enabled": false,
                      "load_balancer_backend_address_pool_id": null,
                      "location": "westeurope",
                      "managed_resource_group_id": "/subscriptions/XXXXXX/resourceGroups/databricks-rg-example-databricks-resources",
                      "managed_resource_group_name": "databricks-rg-example-databricks-resources",
                      "managed_services_cmk_key_vault_key_id": null,
                      "name": "databricks-test",
                      "network_security_group_rules_required": null,
                      "public_network_access_enabled": false,
                      "resource_group_name": "example-databricks-resources",
                      "sku": "standard",
                      "storage_account_identity": [],
                      "tags": {
                         "Environment": "Production"
                      },
                      "timeouts": null,
                      "workspace_id": "XXXXXXX",
                      "workspace_url": "adb-XXXXXX.12.azuredatabricks.net"
                   },
                   "depends_on": [
                      "azurerm_resource_group.example-databricks"
                   ]
                },
                {
                   "address": "azurerm_resource_group.example-databricks",
                   "mode": "managed",
                   "type": "azurerm_resource_group",
                   "name": "example-databricks",
                   "provider_name": "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm",
                   "schema_version": 0,
                   "values": {
                      "id": "/subscriptions/XXXXXX/resourceGroups/example-databricks-resources",
                      "location": "westeurope",
                      "name": "example-databricks-resources",
                      "tags": {},
                      "timeouts": null
                   }
                },
                {
                   "address": "data.azurerm_client_config.current",
                   "mode": "data",
                   "type": "azurerm_client_config",
                   "name": "current",
                   "provider_name": "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm",
                   "schema_version": 0,
                   "values": {
                      "client_id": "XXXXXX",
                      "id": "2021-08-11 06:45:54.6665304 +0000 UTC",
                      "object_id": "XXXXXX",
                      "subscription_id": "XXXXXX",
                      "tenant_id": "***",
                      "timeouts": null
                   }
                },
                {
                   "address": "data.azurerm_subscription.primary",
                   "mode": "data",
                   "type": "azurerm_subscription",
                   "name": "primary",
                   "provider_name": "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm",
                   "schema_version": 0,
                   "values": {
                      "display_name": "sub-dp-das-prod",
                      "id": "/subscriptions/XXXXXX",
                      "location_placement_id": "Public_2014-09-01",
                      "quota_id": "CSP_2015-05-01",
                      "spending_limit": "Off",
                      "state": "Enabled",
                      "subscription_id": "XXXXXX",
                      "tags": {},
                      "tenant_id": "***",
                      "timeouts": null
                   }
                }
             ]
          }
       }
    },
    "configuration": {
       "provider_config": {
          "azuread": {
             "name": "azuread",
             "version_constraint": "=0.7.0",
             "expressions": {
                "client_id": {
                   "constant_value": "__clientid__"
                },
                "subscription_id": {
                   "constant_value": "__subscriptionid__"
                },
                "tenant_id": {
                   "constant_value": "__tenantid__"
                }
             }
          },
          "azurerm": {
             "name": "azurerm",
             "version_constraint": "2.71.0",
             "expressions": {
                "client_id": {
                   "constant_value": "XXXXXX"
                },
                "client_secret": {
                   "constant_value": "XXXXXX"
                },
                "features": [
                   {}
                ],
                "subscription_id": {
                   "constant_value": "XXXXXX"
                },
                "tenant_id": {
                   "constant_value": "***"
                },
                "use_msi": {
                   "constant_value": true
                }
             }
          }
       },
       "root_module": {
          "resources": [
             {
                "address": "azurerm_databricks_workspace.example-databricks",
                "mode": "managed",
                "type": "azurerm_databricks_workspace",
                "name": "example-databricks",
                "provider_config_key": "azurerm",
                "expressions": {
                   "location": {
                      "references": [
                         "azurerm_resource_group.example-databricks"
                      ]
                   },
                   "name": {
                      "constant_value": "databricks-test"
                   },
                   "public_network_access_enabled": {
                      "constant_value": true
                   },
                   "resource_group_name": {
                      "references": [
                         "azurerm_resource_group.example-databricks"
                      ]
                   },
                   "sku": {
                      "constant_value": "standard"
                   },
                   "tags": {
                      "constant_value": {
                         "Environment": "Production"
                      }
                   }
                },
                "schema_version": 0
             },
             {
                "address": "azurerm_resource_group.example-databricks",
                "mode": "managed",
                "type": "azurerm_resource_group",
                "name": "example-databricks",
                "provider_config_key": "azurerm",
                "expressions": {
                   "location": {
                      "constant_value": "West Europe"
                   },
                   "name": {
                      "constant_value": "example-databricks-resources"
                   }
                },
                "schema_version": 0
             },
             {
                "address": "data.azurerm_client_config.current",
                "mode": "data",
                "type": "azurerm_client_config",
                "name": "current",
                "provider_config_key": "azurerm",
                "schema_version": 0
             },
             {
                "address": "data.azurerm_subscription.primary",
                "mode": "data",
                "type": "azurerm_subscription",
                "name": "primary",
                "provider_config_key": "azurerm",
                "schema_version": 0
             }
          ],
          "variables": {
            }
       }
    }
 }
```

**Terraform Plan Text Details**

[Terraform Plan Text Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDfwT.jpg)

Any help will be appreciated in this case. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your plan show when it wants to recreate it?

Comment: How are you maintaining remote state and please share your terraform plan.

Comment: updated with plan details now

Comment: can you put the text output of `teraform plan` ? It should highlight what has changes

Comment: also, try to upgrade to 2.73 - 2.71 had some problems in Databricks resource

Comment: Are you using a backend configuration to maintain your state?